# Change in spring boot API response

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jenkins

I have a Spring Boot application with Mongodb as database and Jenkins as CI server.
This is a sample of the data stored by Jenkins:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("60ed8d8482cd350a2cd9db28"), 
  "buildId" : "35", 
  "wokspace" : "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ACM-JENKINS-API", 
  "remoteUrl" : "http://172.16.4.105:7990/scm/jenkins/acm-jenkins-api.git", 
  "branch" : "origin/branch-youssef", 
  "type" : "back", 
  "date" : "2021-07-13 14:56:36", 
  "description" : "Démarré par l'utilisateur Youssef Boudaya", 
  "backupPath" : "/root/backups_api/backup_35", 
  "projectId" : "60ed8d6a24ac0a5cee63aafe" 
}
```

and This is the API response :

```
{
    "id": "60ed8d8482cd350a2cd9db28",
    "build_id": "35",
    "workspace": null,
    "remote_url": "http://172.16.4.105:7990/scm/jenkins/acm-jenkins-api.git",
    "branch": "origin/branch-youssef",
    "description": "Démarré par l'utilisateur Youssef Boudaya",
    "type": "back",
    "date": "2021-07-13 14:56:36",
    "project_id": "60ed8d6a24ac0a5cee63aafe",
    "backup_path": "/root/backups_api/backup_35"
}
```

I want to know why there is difference in the columns names.
My entity in Spring boot:

```
/** The id. */
private String id;

/** The build id. */
// Build id de jenkins
private String buildId;

/** The workspace. */
private String workspace;

/** The remote url. */
private String remoteUrl;

/** The branch. */
private String branch;

/** The description. */
private String description;

/** The type. */
private String type;

/** The date. */
private String date;

/** The project id. */
private String projectId;

/** The backup path. */
private String backupPath;
```

and the DTO has the exact structure of the model class.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot Entites Members convert Capital letter to  under score in the coulmns names.
i means
myName  will be my_name in the database
this is the behavior

Comment: so how should i store my jenkins info in the mongo database ?

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya i guess u can use Annotations .
and after connect to database 
table will generated automatically.
but anyway u should u can use the same properties names in both spring boot and database .